# SQL Agent Job dependency

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

I have a requirement is SQL Agent Jobs where their is a job called Job 4 which dependent on 3 other jobs say Job 1, Job 2 and Job 3. So this Job 4 has to be triggered whenever either one of the 3 jobs i.e. Job 1, Job 2 and Job 3 gets succeeded. Since days I have been breaking my head on this but unable to figure anything out. Can you please help me on this?

Thanks in advance 
Manoj

Answer (score 1):

In each of Jobs 1, 2, and 3, add a second step. (Or a step after all of the other steps, if these are already multi-step jobs.)  Have that new step be:

```
exec sp_start_job 'Job 4'
```

And because you mention that you only want Job 4 to be started if the other jobs succeed, you should also adjust the Advanced properties of the existing final step in each of Jobs 1, 2, and 3 to be:

```
On success action: Go to the next step
On failure action: Quit the job reporting failure
```